# Socket connection request refused

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to have a Socket connection between my laptop and my Android.

I am making laptop as a server. To establish the connection, I am using the IP of laptop as shown by `ipconfig` (running Windows 7) (this address is not the same as shown by websites like 'whatismyip').

Things work fine when I connect both my laptop and Android to the same wireless router and I use the address given by ipconfig.

However, when I use the EDGE connection of my Android and access the same IP address, the Socket connection request is refused. Also, the IP given by whatismyip doesn't work either with WLAN or EDGE.

I have heard that there are two IP addresses, internal and external. And I suppose that the address given by ipconfig is the internal address. Also, there is some procedure called as port forwarding.

Can someone please help me to access the ServerSocket via the EDGE connection? Which IP should I use for that, and if I need to do port forwarding, how can it be done?
Thanks.

Comment: This belongs either on http://superuser.com or the android-specific user Q&A site (http://android.stackexchange.com/).  It is not a *programming* problem.

Comment: But the android connectivity part is not an issue, rather, I think it will work fine if I try to connect to the proper IP address or something like port forwarding.. :)

Comment: Selecting the right IP address is largely a matter of knowing which is the right one to put into your app's config files (or whatever).  Port forwarding is implemented in the Android system's iptables.  Neither of these have anything to do with programming ... and hence this Question is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

On your laptop, when you run the ipconfig command, the ip address it shows on whatever interface you are connecting to your router with is a private address (not a routable address).  The IP address shown by whatismyip is the IP address assigned to your modem.  When your phone is connected to your router over Wi-Fi, you are within the same subnet as your laptop, and are able to create a connection.  When you are on the EDGE network, you are on a different subnet, and since your laptop's IP is not routable, you can't connect to it.  On most routers, you can configure all ingress traffic for a destination port to be sent to your laptop.  The configuration for this varies for each router, but the idea is the same.  The IP address you want to forward this traffic to is the private IP address of your laptop (the one shown by ipconfig), and the port is whichever port the traffic you are sending is destined for.

Comment: +1 this is known as port forwarding